# ReactJs Check Validity of HTTP Request Response

Tags: reactjs

I am wondering if there is a way to check if the response type is parsable into a specific type:

```
interface ExpectedResponse
{
  anInteger: number;
  aBoolean: bool;
  aString: string;
}

function sendRequest() : Promise<ExpectedRespnse>
{
  const response = await <HTTP call>
  return response as ExpectedResponse;
}
```

In this example, if the response data can be mapped 1:1 to the interface, everything is fine. The object will be treated as an ExpectedResponse object when automatically deserialized.

Is there a way to ensure that the response data is `ExpectedResponse` with all required attributes filled and no "undefined" attributes not filled?

Comment: You could write a custom serialize function that cleans up the response to look like the interface that's one way to ensure it matches.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought about this but that solution isn't scalable. At face value, I believe it would be very cumbersome to do this with all HTTP request response objects as the number of them increases. If there's a way to pass the response and interface type into a function to check if they match, that would also solve my issue.

Comment: That's the point, it's best to ensure the server returns the expected response. If you're asking whether you can manipulate HTTP request's response data automatically. The answer is. you can't